# Not all nodes are showing up in UAExpert when connected to Kepware OPC UA server

Tags: opc-ua, opc, kepserverex

I am trying to jump into OPC UA.  I have a test KepServerEX OPC server set up with UA enabled.  Have the two default endpoints setup and enabled.  I am using UAExpert to connect to the OPC server so I can browse tags.  I connect just fine, but the only node showing up is the server node.  There should be at least 3 other nodes showing because there are 3 channels set up with a device in each.  Two of these are simulation devices that have tags defined, the other is a connection to a PLC.  I cannot seem to get those other nodes to show up. I looked everywhere for any kind of settings that might prevent browsing of these nodes.  I cannot find anything.  Both client and server are running on the same computer.  Any ideas?

Tried searching the internet and the Kepware documentation.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.